# Is there a way to sort an array of numbers in liquid

Tags: arrays, sorting, shopify, liquid

I am trying to sort an array of number in liquid I have try like the following example:

```
{% assign numbers = "248 (3), 32 (7), 415 (5), " | split: ", " %}
{% assign sortedNumbers = numbers | sort %}

{% for numb in sortedNumbers -%}
  {{ numb }}
{%- endfor %}
```

The output of this is:
248 (3)
32 (7)
415 (5)

but expected: 32 (7)
248 (3)
415 (5)

do you know how I could sort the array in the expected way?

Comment: As your array is not including real integers you won't be able to achieve it by using the sort filter which consider elements as strings (so 2 comes before 3 and so on).